# Error while importing contacts from AOL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, aol, import-contacts

I am trying to import all my AOL Email contacts in my web application. For that I am using [cardmagic gem](https://github.com/cardmagic/contacts.git) given at

I forked the code &  replaced following code

```
AOL_NUM = "29970-343" # this seems to change each time they change the protocol

CONTACT_LIST_URL = "http://webmail.aol.com/#{AOL_NUM}/aim-2/en-us/Lite/ContactList.aspx?folder=Inbox&showUserFolders=False"

CONTACT_LIST_CSV_URL = "http://webmail.aol.com/#{AOL_NUM}/aim-2/en-us/Lite/ABExport.aspx?command=all"
```

with

```
AOL_NUM = "32992-111" # this seems to change each time they change the protocol

CONTACT_LIST_URL    = "http://mail.aol.com/#{AOL_NUM}/aol-6/en-us/Lite/ContactList.aspx?folder=Inbox&showUserFolders=False"

CONTACT_LIST_CSV_URL = "http://mail.aol.com/#{AOL_NUM}/aol-6/en-us/Lite/ABExport.aspx?command=all"
```

Still I am getting error

```
CSV::IllegalFormatError: CSV::IllegalFormatError
```

Is this due to outdated AOl_NUM? or are there any more changes in the aol.rb?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it should work. Did you perform update bundle after including the gem? perform `bundle update` and restart your server.